# maple plotting a set of data points from a file

Tags: maple

I have the following data list in a file, say mydata.txt

> 0 -2.900125720 -253.200 \ 1 -5.512974510 -253.800 \ 9 -398.4569435
>   -253.16 \ 10 -748.4988836 -253.19 \

I read the file in as readdata(mydata.txt, float, 3) and this generates a data list, say

> mydatalist := [[0., -2.900125720, -2531.200], [1.0, -5.512974510,
>   -253.800], [2.0, -8.690644103, -253.168], [9.0, -398.4569435, -253.16], [10.0, -748.4988836, -253.19]]

How do I plot with Maple (say) the third column against the first column (i.e. first column are x values, third column are y values)?

Answer (score 2):

There are more powerful ways to read in large amounts of data such as the command `ImportMatrix`, which can get you to a float[8] Matrix (more efficiently used than a listlist).

But, starting with such a list of lists,

```
mydatalist := [[0., -2.900125720, -253.200],
               [1.0, -5.512974510, -253.800],
               [2.0, -8.690644103, -253.168],
               [9.0, -398.4569435, -253.16],
               [10.0, -748.4988836, -253.19]]:

M := Matrix(mydatalist,datatype=float[8]):

M[..,[1,3]];

plot(M[..,[1,3]]);

plot(M[..,[1,3]], style=point);
```